# Area of curves that intersect at more than two points

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to set up a definite integral but the examples shown in my textbook and the way that my textbook solved the problem doesn't match.

The problem I'm trying to solve is $y_1= 3(x^3-x)$ and $y_2 = 0$.
The way that the textbook solved this problem looks like this:

> $ A = 2\int_{-1}^0 3(x^3-x)dx = 6\int_{-1}^0 (x^3-x)dx$ or $-6\int_0^1(x^3-x)dx$

Where I'm confused is where did they get the **2** that is in front of $\int_{-1}^0$?

The textbooks shows an example that solves area of $f(x)=3x^3-x^2-10x$ and $g(x)=-x^2+2x$ like so:

> $A = \int_{-2}^0[f(x)-g(x)]dx + \int_0^2[g(x)-f(x)]dx$

But the way they setup the definite integral in the example doesn't seem to be same as the problem. Could someone elaborate why is that? *And if possible in plain English would great.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the graph of $y=f(x)=x^3-x$, or have software do it for you.  This is **very** important, for if you don't what is written below will be "just words."

Note that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$. That means that the graph for $x$ negative is the graph for positive $x$, rotated through $180^\circ$, or equivalently reflected in a point mirror at the origin. The computation you quoted takes advantage of the **symmetry**.

From $x=-1$ to $x=0$, our function $f(x)$ is positive, the curve is above the $x$-axis. From $0$ to $1$, we have $f(x)\le 0$. So to find the total area of the region caught between the curve and the $x$-axis, we find the area of the chunk from $-1$ to $0$, and double.

Another way of doing it is to note that between $-1$ and $0$, $f(x)$ is above the $x$-axis, and from $0$ to $1$ it is below. So the total area is
$$\int_{-1}^0 \left((x-x^3)-0\right)\,dx + \int_{0}^1 \left(0-(x-x^3)\right)\,dx.$$
The two integrals are equal, so we might as well only compute one of them and double the result.

Comment: Ok, it's starting to make sense. Could you elaborate more on the "double" part?

Comment: In the way the textbook solved the problem, when they added that **2** in front of $\int_{-1}^0$, were they saying that the answer would be symmetrical? There fore there would be two answers that would be positive or negative?

Comment: The part from $0$ to $1$ has exactly the same shape as the part between $-1$ and $0$, except turned upside down. Together, they form a vaguely propeller-shape. To find the area of the whole propeller, you take the area of the left-half and double the result. But you can also compute them separately, as towards the end of my answer. The thing one **must** not do is integrate $x-x^3$ from $-1$ to $1$. Because the left half is above the $x$-axis and the right half is below, the integral will be $0$.

Comment: Ok, so to straighten my mind, if I double the definite integral using the left-half, the answer will "always" be positive or negative. Correct?

Comment: There are not two answers, this is a real propeller, it cannot have a negative area. They are doubling the area of the left half because the area of the right half is the same as the area of the left half. If you know that A and B have the same number of marbles, then to find the total they have between them, it is enough to count A's marbles and double the result.

Comment: On your last comment, I don't know what you mean. If you double a positive number you get a positive, if you double a negative you get a negative. The doubling strategy only works here because of the **symmetry**. Hope you have seen a diagram. Wolfram Alpha will do it for you.

Comment: There was a typo, I had chnk from $-1$ to $1$ where it should be chunk from $-1$ to $0$. Now corrected.